# How to solve : Unable to Process Jar entry

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting this error on console. Can anyone please help me out (I am working on a Spring MVC project with GWT and maven)

> SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry
>   [com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class] from Jar
>   [jar:file:/C:/Users/ayush/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/transconnect/WEB-INF/lib/icu4j-2.6.1.jar!/]
>   for annotations org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Cl

Comment: Did you get solution for it?

Comment: I also received this warning/error on the console of a project that I undertook. However with me the error was happening on a gradle build and after updating some jackson dependencies, clearing cache and building again, the error dissapeared

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same problem by simply replacing the icu4j-2.6.1.jar with latest jar

click [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloadicu4j40jar.htm) to download latest version of jar

Hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

So, in our case it didn't come from a direct dependency but rather from an indirect injection of the `com.google.code.findbugs` library.

You will know where it comes from by running `mvn dependency:tree` for your project (supposing you're using maven)

Solution for us was to use a newer version of the findbugs library (3.0.0) which appeared to be much leaner in terms of dependency content.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class` file is missing in jar try replacing the [jar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.ibm.icu/jars/icu4j-2.6.1.jar.html?all=true).

Comment: I checked the jaar file, it contains LocaleElements_zh_PINYIN.class file. I even tried redownloading the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

com.ibm.icu.impl.data.LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN  is a ill-formed class file inside the 2.6.1 icu4j jar file. Override or use the newer icu4j jar files, 55.0+.

Answer (score 0):

First open the file icu4j-2.6.1.jar with any zip vievwer (7Zip for example). Check if it contains the com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class file.

Comment: I checked the jaar file, it contains LocaleElements_zh_PINYIN.class file. I even tried redownloading the jar file.

Comment: Googling the error "Unable to process Jar entry [com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class]" throws some results, it seems some bug with BCEL... it seems to be fixed now. May be you only have to update the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when icu4j-xxx.jar is included in my class path. Why don't you try to remove it from your WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 0):

For me, upgrade tomcat to `tomcat-8.0.37` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
  <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
  <version>4.6</version>
</dependency>
```