# Android Studio showing error while importing old eclipse project with dependencies

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I am getting the error as below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':pinaka:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\abhishek.jha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.ibm.icu\icu4j\2.6.1\ec0b2437fa48825d7b046efafbe8d27343fe97b2\icu4j-2.6.1.jar'.
```

I have tried these links but nothing seems to be working out in my case, Please do have a look, Thanks in advance.

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3426

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-expand-zip-error-while-using-incremental-java-compilation/15689

[How to solve : Unable to Process Jar entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701319/how-to-solve-unable-to-process-jar-entry)